# Upload .txt para banco de dados MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, upload, file-upload, txt

Olá,

Gostaria de fazer o upload de um arquivo `.txt` que se encontra com o layout da seguinte forma (segue exemplo de duas linhas do arquivo):

```
9787546;488464;2016-12-11;Carlos Fonseca;carlos.fonseca
9787547;464664;2016-12-11;Rogério Barros;rogerio.barros
```

O arquivo mantém este layout e possui mais de 3 mil linhas.

Gostaria de saber mais ou menos um script que trate as linhas, diferenciando em colunas cada dado.

O que tenho atualmente simples, porém importa apenas a primeira coluna:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('../files/docs/libs/newUsers.txt', 'r');

while(!feof($file)){
    $data = fgets($file);
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"insert into users values '({$data})'");
}
```

Sei que não está sendo feita nenhuma separação das colunas, porém foi o máximo que encontrei no momento.

Ainda não codifico em OO.

Obrigado!

Comment: a tabela users está com qual layout? (ou seja, os campos para inserção, você não especificou na SQL isso não é muito apropriado.)

Comment: É verdade o @VirgilioNovic, tem razão. Deves jogar pelo seguro e especificar colunas e respetivos valores

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu não especifiquei a principio as colunas pois o layout trata-se de todas as colunas presentes nesta tabela, mas vou especificar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimenta isto:

```
$file = fopen('../files/docs/libs/newUsers.txt', 'r');

while(!feof($file)){
    $data = explode(';', fgets($file)); // separar valores pelos ; que estão no ficheiro
    $query = mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO users (COL1, COL2,COL3, COL4, COL5) VALUES (' .implode(', ', $data). ')');
}
```

Não é obrigatório, mas eu aconcelho a jogar pelo seguro e especificar o nome das colunas na query também.

Deves substituir os COL.. Pelas nome das colunas respetivas que tens na tabela `users`, sendo que a primeira (`COL1`) corresponde ao primeiro valor etc...

Comment: Obrigado @Miguel, atende perfeitamente ao proposto!

Comment: De nada @jvbarsou, ainda bem que resolveu

Comment: de fato não conhecia muito sobre o implode e explode, agora vai ser bem útil hehehehe

Comment: Aos poucos vais aprendendo, "a prática faz o mestre" @jvbarsou